# Finding a Matrix of Rank 10 using Taylor Expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

For $-1\leq t_i\le 1$ and $1\le i\le n$, we have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $$A_{ij}=\exp(t_it_j)$$ 
Now, how can we use the Taylor expansion of $e^x $ to find a $\text{rank }10$ matrix $$B_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_{ki}b_{kj}$$ with $|A_{ij}-B_{ij}|\le 10^{-6}\:\forall i,j$.

**My Thoughts:**

First of all $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

So this reminded me of the matrix exponential function for some reason. I don't know how much this will help for this problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really the matrix exponential because you're doing things entrywise rather than using matrix multiplication.

You want to try $$B_{ij} = \sum_{m=0}^9 (t_i t_j)^m/m! = \sum_{k=1}^{10} a_{ki} b_{kj}$$
where $a_{ki} = t_i^{k-1}/(k-1)!$ and $b_{kj} = t_j^{k-1}$.
Note that for each $k$ the matrix with entries $a_{ki} b_{kj}$
has rank at most $1$, so $B$ has rank at most $10$.  It's incorrect to say 
"rank $10$", since that's clearly impossible if $n < 10$.

For $-1 < t < 1$, by Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder $$\left|\exp(t) - \sum_{k=0}^9 \dfrac{t^k}{k!} \right| \le 
 \dfrac{e}{10!} < 10^{-6}$$
so that $|A_{ij} - B_{ij}| < 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I'm still not understanding how this would lead me to finding the matrix.

Comment: Could you add more to your answer? I'm still having trouble understanding what you are showing.

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with $a_{ki}$ and $b_{kj}$

Comment: 10 terms of the Taylor series for $\exp(t_i t_j)$.  Each $k$ gets one of them.

Comment: You are finding a matrix.  The matrix has the entries $B_{ij}$.

Comment: Ok and one more thing. Where did the $\frac{e}{10!}$ come from?

Comment: The Lagrange form for the [remainder in Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).  Note that $f^{(k+1)}(\xi) = e^\xi < e$ if $-1 < \xi < 1$.